# Query with multiple parameters not working in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, parameterized-query

Here is the Query

```
SELECT Distinct NSS.RevisionId,NSS.SheetName,NSS.SubmitId,NSS.FileName,
NSS.UpdateTimeA,NSS.UpdateUserId,NSS.NG, NSS.Complete, CD.ControlName, NSS.ItemName,
NSS.ItemValue, NSS.ExternalFile 
FROM (
SELECT rs.SheetName ,rs.SubmitId,rs.FileName,rs.UpdateTimeA,rs.UpdateUserId,rs.NG,
rs.Complete, rd.ItemName, rd.ItemValue, rs.RevisionId, rd.ExternalFile


    FROM Revisions AS rs
INNER JOIN RevisionsData AS rd 
ON rs.SubmitId = rd.SubmitId AND  rs.RevisionId = rd.RevisionId
WHERE rs.FileSubmitId = @FileSubmitId  AND rs.SheetName= @SheetName 
AND (  rd.RevisionId = @RevisionId1 OR rd.RevisionId = @RevisionId2  ) 
AND (  rd.ItemName IN ( @ItemName1 , @ItemName2 , @ItemName3 , @ItemName4 , @ItemName5 ,
 @ItemName6 , @ItemName7 , @ItemName8 , @ItemName9 , @ItemName10 , @ItemName11 ,
 @ItemName12 , @ItemName13 , @ItemName14 , @ItemName15 , @ItemName16 ) )) AS NSS

        LEFT JOIN CSVData AS CD
        ON NSS.ItemName = CD.ControlKey
        WHERE CD.FileId = @FileId
        Order By NSS.RevisionId desc
```

and here is the error

```
The variable name '@RevisionId1' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique
 within a query batch or stored procedure.
Must declare the scalar variable "@RevisionId2"
```

this query is perfectly working in MS Access 2010 but in SQL Server 2005 it gives error.

and this is how i am creating this query

```
cmd.CommandText = String.Format(@"SELECT Distinct  NSS.RevisionId,NSS.SheetName,NSS.SubmitId,NSS.FileName,NSS.UpdateTimeA,NSS.UpdateUserId,NSS.NG, NSS.Complete, CD.ControlName, NSS.ItemName, NSS.ItemValue, NSS.ExternalFile FROM (
                                                SELECT rs.SheetName ,rs.SubmitId,rs.FileName,rs.UpdateTimeA,rs.UpdateUserId,rs.NG, rs.Complete, rd.ItemName, rd.ItemValue, rs.RevisionId, rd.ExternalFile
                                                                                        FROM Revisions AS rs 
                                                                                        INNER JOIN RevisionsData AS rd 
                                                                                        ON rs.SubmitId = rd.SubmitId AND  rs.RevisionId = rd.RevisionId
                                                                                        WHERE rs.FileSubmitId = @FileSubmitId  AND rs.SheetName= @SheetName AND ( {0} ) AND ( {1} )) AS NSS
                                                LEFT JOIN CSVData AS CD
                                                ON NSS.ItemName = CD.ControlKey
                                                WHERE CD.FileId = @FileId
                                                Order By NSS.RevisionId desc", strRevisionQuery, strItemsQuery);

                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileSubmitId", FileSubmitId);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SheetName", sheet.Name);
                            // Revisions
                            intRevisionIndex = 1;
                            foreach (var revisionId in dIndexAndRevisionId)
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RevisionId" + intRevisionIndex, revisionId.Key);
                            }
                            //Sheets Name && Item Name
                            intItemsIndex = 1;
                            foreach (var gItems in sheet.g)
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemName" + intItemsIndex, gItems[0]);
                                intItemsIndex++;
                            }
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileId", FileId);
```

Comment: This is not the whole query.

Comment: I will just leave this here. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
intRevisionIndex = 1;
foreach (var revisionId in dIndexAndRevisionId)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RevisionId" + intRevisionIndex, revisionId.Key);
}
```

`intRevisionIndex` is never incremented.

Therefore `"@RevisionId" + intRevisionIndex` = `@RevisionId1` every time.